# Java Regex Pattern for getting text between digits in parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have the following sample of Text, with new lines:

```
(2) County
HAW
(3) District
PN
(4) Beat
831
(5) Watch
2
(6) Date/Time/Day Occurred
11/19/2019 14:47 TU
(7) Date/Time/Day Reported
11/19/2019 14:47 TU
```

I am trying to come up with a RegEx pattern so that I could put the text, extracted from 
a String with new lines
into a HashMap with a key for each new line, and iteratively be able to put the text strings into the map something like this:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
m.put("(2) County","HAW"
m.put("(3) District","PN"
m.put("(4) Beat","831"
m.put("(6) Date/Time/Day Occurred","11/19/2019 14:47 TU"
m.put("(5) Watch","2"
m.put("(7) Date/Time/Day Reported","11/19/2019 14:47 TU"
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself yet?  You are asking for at least 20+ lines of Java code.

Comment: Why use a reg exp and not read line by line (See https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file)

Comment: "(?<=//(//d//))"  I think I need some type  positive lookbehind assertion to apply to the String, and then I can iterate across the matches and put the Key and Value from the extracted text. But I am struggling with the pattern to break it into a series of key values

Comment: I agree with R.Groote. Instead of regex just read the text and put all the text from odd line as map key and those from even line as map value.

Comment: Why do you need Regex for this problem?

Comment: How else would I do this ?

Comment: You can split by new line character and put them in map? If you want a solution and don't need regex, I can post it as answer

Comment: This the pattern that I came up with : ```Map<String, String> formMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{1,3}[A-Z]?\\)(.*)");

  String[] result = pattern.split(input);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

  for (int i = 1; matcher.find(); i++) {
   System.out.println("Token " + i + ": " + matcher.group() + ", value : "+result[i]);
   
   String key = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(matcher.group().toString());
   String value = result[i].trim();
   formMap.put(key, value);
  
  }````

Answer (score 0):

Getting closer, Can this be optimized ?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d\\)(.*)");
        String INPUT   =  "(2) County\n" + 
                "HAW\n" + 
                "(3) District\n" +
                "PA\n"  ;

        String[] result = pattern.split(INPUT);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);


        final Map<String, String> matches = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.put(matcher.group(0).trim(),result[i].trim());
            i++;
        }


        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : matches.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
```